# node-cron with timezones

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, timezone

i have a [node](http://nodejs.org/)(v0.7.3-pre) server with [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron)(0.3.2) and [node-time](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-time)(0.8.2):

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var cronJ = new cronJob({
 cronTime: "00 29 16 6 * *",
 onTick: function() {
  console.log("Tick");
 },
 start:true,
 timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
});
console.log(cronJ);
```

it runs, but the Cron is allways working with the server time(UTC), and the returned cron is:

```
{ _callbacks: [ [Function] ],
  onComplete: undefined,
  cronTime:
   { source: '00 29 16 6 * *',
     zone: undefined,
     second: { '0': true },
     minute: { '29': true },
     hour: { '16': true },
     dayOfWeek:
...
```

the `zone` is set as `undefined`, am i missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because an error in node-cron module. I already send a [pull request](https://github.com/baryshev/node-cron/commit/912fb5e07d61458d36d1d39d62a28461d65ed9be) that will fix it. You can change this lines in your local copy of this module.

You also can use several function parameters to initialize cronJob instead of one object:

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var cronJ = new cronJob("00 29 16 6 * *", function() {
        console.log("Tick");
}, undefined, true, "America/Los_Angeles");

console.log(cronJ);
```