# Are node-cron and cron modules in npm same?

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduler, node-cron

I'm trying to implement a cron job scheduler in my node api. When i went over search i see there are two modules. node-cron and cron. With reference to the below question, it adds to my confusion, as the user has node-cron installed on his machine whereas in his code he imports cron module.

[Node-cron example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918541/node-cron-with-timezones)

When i search npmjs for module i see two different modules

[Node-cron and cron modules in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=node-cron)

Not sure if i'm completely misunderstanding the concept or what.

Please suggest.!

Answer (score 0):

They are different packages that do the same thing. In the example, the user says he he is using node-cron but he is just using cron.